# Java Generics code error

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Generics and trying to understand why this code compiles:

```
public Collection<Class<Subclass>> testFunction() {

    return Collections.singleton(Subclass.class);
}
```

And this code doesn't:

```
public Collection<Class<? extends SuperClass>> testFunction() {

    return Collections.singleton(Subclass.class);
}
```

My SubClass looks like this:

```
public class Subclass extends SuperClass{

}
```

Comment: both of them should compile fine (java 8), the given question doesn't relate to this issue

Comment: @Eran it that might depend on the Java version you're using, i.e. if the type inference works correctly `Collections.singleton(Integer.class);` should create a `Collection<Class<? extends Number>>` but if it doesn't (and older compilers had problems here) you'll get a type conflict.

Comment: @Eran On eclipse-neon, with jdk 8 it gives the following error message:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Class<Integer>> to Collection<Class<? extends Number>>

Comment: @Vaibhav Eclipse has it's own compiler (`eclipsec`), but it works fine for mars. You can help out the compiler by providing the explicit type: `Collections.<Class<? extends SuperClass>>singleton(Subclass.class);`

Comment: @Vaibhav I am running eclipse-neon with JDK8 ... and I dont get that error. Could it be that you enabled the "compatibility" mode to java7 within your project/workspace preferences?

Comment: @JornVernee Yes, It works for me on Mars too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above compiles **fine** with Java8:

```
class SuperClass { }
class Subclass extends SuperClass{ }

class Test {
  public Collection<Class<? extends SuperClass>> testFunction() {
    return Collections.singleton(Subclass.class);
  }
}
```

The point is: with Java **8**, type inference was heavily reworked and improved.

So my *guess* here is: this doesn't compile for you because you are using Java 7; where simply spoken the compiler wasn't "good enough" to correctly  resolve such kind of code.

Comment: Here's the problem that I was facing. Your code compiles on java8 for me too now. Earlier eclipse didn't build the project with java8 compiler hence the error was there.